# How do I get rid of the control characters in emacs --debug init

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

When running emacs with --debug-init, I get garbled output in my debug information.  It looks to me like emacs isnn't processing color control information, but that's just a guess.  Copy paste doesn't accurately reflect the output.  It looks something like this:

```
load("~.emacs" t t)
#[0 "^H\205\262^@    \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ (etc)
```

Comment: Did you byte-compile your .emacs?

Comment: not intentionally/explicitly.

Comment: Well, it's byte-code. (It's from startup.elc) But it shouldn't be all you see.

Comment: It's not all I see.  I am able to debug the problem, but I'm not able to use this particular output for anything. I thought it might be possible to set up emacs so it displays it in a a more meaningful fashion.  If I knew more about byte code would this output be useful to me?

Comment: Rather unlikely. Below that line you should see something like `(command-line)`. `command-line` calls an anonymous function (the "garbled" output), which in turn loads your .emacs. Your problem is further to the top.

Comment: BTW, if you are really interested in what is going on (and you have the sources), you can call `src/temacs --debug-init` in the emacs directory.

Comment: If copy-paste isn't accurate, could you add a screenshot?